# Trying to present records with nested attributes in an index format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm stumped.  I have a Task Dashboard that is supposed to list an index of tasks (@tasks = Task.all), but I can't figure out how to call its associated nested records without said record returning the values from ALL Tasks.  Any ideas how I can limit the scope of the nested attributes to return only the values of its associated Task?

tasks_controller.rb -->

```
  def dashboard
    @tasks = Task.all

    @taskproduct = TaskProduct.select(:product_id) # .where(:task_id => @tasks.id)
    @item = Item.where(:id => @taskproduct)

    @storeorders = Storeorder.all
    @storeorderid = Storeorder.select(:store_id) # .where(:task_id => @tasks.id)
    @store = Store.where(:id => @storeorderid)
  end
```

task.rb -->

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :storeorder, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :task_products
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :storeorder, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:store_id].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :task_products
end
```

task_product.rb -->

```
class TaskProduct < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :task
  has_many :items
end
```

dashboard.html.erb -->

```
<tbody>
          <% @tasks.each do |t| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= link_to t.task_name, task_path(id: t.id) %></td>
<!-- PRODUCTS ORDERED -->
            <td>
              <% @item.each do |i| %>
                <p><%= link_to i.item_select, item_path(id: i.id) %></p>
              <% end %>
            </td>

            <td><%= t.notes %></td>
<!-- SHIPPING ADDRESS -->
            <% @storeorders.each do |so| %>

              <% @store.each do |s| %>
                <td>
                  <p><%= link_to s.store_identifier, store_path(id: s.id) %></p>
                  <p><%= s.address %></p>
                  <p><%= s.city %>, <%= s.state %> <%= s.zipcode %></p>
                </td>
              <% end %>

              <td><%= so.po_number %></td>
            <% end %>
          </tr>
          <% end %>
        </tbody>
```

The '#.where(:task_id => @tasks.id)' is basically what I'm trying to accomplish, although I know that's not the proper syntax.

The Task Products table logs an item_id that I can then reference with @item, however, instead of returning the Task Products from the task_id it is associated with, it returns all Task Products in the table.  I think I understand why this is happening, I just don't know how to properly scope it.  Same thing is happening with the Storeorder nested attribute, but I figure I can duplicate whatever solution is needed for TaskProducts over to that one.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the [includes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) method.

You can query all of a tasks associations this way.

```
@tasks = Task.includes(:task_products, :store_order)
```

You can than acess each Task's task products and store order like so

```
task = @task.first
# get all associated task products
task.task_products
# get store order
task.store_order
# iterate all tasks
@tasks.each do |task|
  #iterate all task_products
  task.task_products.each do |task_product|
  end
  #iterate store order
  task.store_order do |store_order|
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @userFriendly!  I did a test with this method and managed to tidy up the table a bit with some of the code, but I still need to be able to retrieve multiple tasks and their nested associations into a table format.  This method only seems to work with selecting a single task ID?

Comment: Thanks again @userFriendly.  Still a beginner, so apologies for one more question.  We're almost there!  I got the table to correctly display each task_product id per task, and each store_order id, however I need to relate these id's to another non-associated table.  each task_product has a product_id that correlates to an item in my Items table (as seen in my original view file up top).  Any idea how I can convert the product_id to the Item values in my view?  I tried adding a '@item' database call within the 'task.task_products.each do', but that only returns the last value in the table.